# How to Draw a Pause Button using WPF Path

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing a VideoTransport control from scratch in WPF, which looks like YouTube's. It is going reasonable well and looking very nice - animated etc. I am writing this control from the ground up so that it is fully extensible and MVVM freindly (you can take part if you wish https://github.com/Camuvingian/symmetrical-spork).

Now, to generate the play button I use the following code

```
controlGrid = GetTemplateChild("PART_ControlGrid") as Grid;
controlGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = GridLength.Auto });
controlGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = GridLength.Auto });
controlGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = GridLength.Auto });
controlGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = GridLength.Auto });
controlGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = GridLength.Auto });
controlGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
controlGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = GridLength.Auto });
controlGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = GridLength.Auto });
controlGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = GridLength.Auto });

Path playButton = CreatePlayButton();
Grid.SetColumn(playButton, 0);
controlGrid.Children.Add(playButton);
```

Where the `CreatePlayButton` method is

```
private Path CreatePlayButton()
{
    Path p = new Path();

    p.StrokeThickness = 0.0;
    p.Fill = Brushes.Gray;

    p.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    p.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;

    Point start = new Point(PlayButtonSize * 0.8, PlayButtonSize / 2.0);
    LineSegment[] segments = new[]
    {
        new LineSegment(new Point(0, 0), true),
        new LineSegment(new Point(0, PlayButtonSize), true)
    };
    PathFigure figure = new PathFigure(start, segments, true);
    PathGeometry geometry = new PathGeometry(new[] { figure });

    p.Margin = new Thickness(16.0, 0, 0, 8.0);
    p.Data = geometry;

    p.MouseEnter += (s, e) => { p.Fill = Brushes.LightGray; };
    p.MouseLeave += (s, e) => { p.Fill = Brushes.Gray; };

    return p;
}
```

This create the correct shape and I am happy with it.

[image: VideoTransportControl]

Now, I would like to create a pause button shape, you know the one with two vertically parrallel rectangles, the issues is, how is this done in code in WPF. I have tried adding the following method

```
private Path CreatePauseButton()
{
    Path p = new Path();

    p.StrokeThickness = 0.0;
    p.Fill = Brushes.Gray;

    p.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    p.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;

    double f = 1.0 / 7.0;
    Point start = new Point(PlayButtonSize * f, 0.0);
    LineSegment[] segments = new[]
    {
        new LineSegment(new Point(PlayButtonSize * f, PlayButtonSize), true),
        new LineSegment(new Point((PlayButtonSize * f) * 3.0, PlayButtonSize), true),
        new LineSegment(new Point((PlayButtonSize * f) * 3.0, 0.0), true),
        new LineSegment(new Point(PlayButtonSize * f, 0.0), true),
        new LineSegment(new Point((PlayButtonSize * f) * 4, PlayButtonSize), false),
        new LineSegment(new Point((PlayButtonSize * f) * 6, PlayButtonSize), true),
        new LineSegment(new Point((PlayButtonSize * f) * 6, 0.0), true),
        new LineSegment(new Point((PlayButtonSize * f) * 4, 0.0), true)
    };

    PathFigure figure = new PathFigure(start, segments, true);
    PathGeometry geometry = new PathGeometry(new[] { figure });

    p.Margin = new Thickness(16.0, 0, 0, 8.0);
    p.Data = geometry;

    p.MouseEnter += (s, e) => { p.Fill = Brushes.LightGray; };
    p.MouseLeave += (s, e) => { p.Fill = Brushes.Gray; };

    return p;
}
```

But this renders the line I have told it not to. Question:

1. How can I draw the pause button I require?

Thanks for your time.

Ps. Please note, this is a work in progress and if anyone has any comments as to things I might not be doing write here, they are more than welcome.

Comment: Do you have a requirement to create the Path with code? If not i'd recommend to store your pause button in a Xaml resource file

This website offers icons as Xaml paths

https://materialdesignicons.com/icon/pause

Here's how the pause button looks like

<Path Data="M14,19H18V5H14M6,19H10V5H6V19Z" />

Comment: You can learn XAML path definition syntax in 15 minutes and make your own icons, trivially in the case of rectangle stuff like "pause". Don't do it in C#, that's masochistic.

Comment: Okay cool, I thought about a tool to do this right after I asked the question. These comments are really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure why I have two down votes though, it is a well formed question?

Answer (score 2):

All images always should be in Vector grafic.

We must install some app before create a new icon for WPF.

```
1) Adobe Illistrator
2) Microsoft Expression Design
3) Blend for Visual Studio Actualy, he alredy installed with Visual Studio
```

1) Why Adobe Illistrator? Because he can create any image in Vector and save file with extension ".AI"

2) After that we should open Microsoft Expression Design

```
[Step 1] - Open File -> Export
[Step 2] - Check Format -> WPF Canvas -> Export
```

3) Open Blend

```
[Step 3] - Create WPF application - add exported pause.xaml file to project
```

[Step 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuHRL.png)  - Combine path

```
[Step 5] - Cut only tag Path
```

3)Go to your project

Set in resources

```
  <DataTemplate x:Key="PICloud">
            <Grid Background="Transparent">
                <Path 
                      Stretch="Fill"
                      Fill="#FFEBEBEB" 
                      Data="F1 M 451.211,145.756C 454.285,138.679 456,130.875 456,122.667C 456,90.6346 430.033,64.6666 398,64.6666C 386.175,64.6666 375.183,68.2133 366.011,74.2906C 352.761,31.2693 312.703,0 265.333,0C 232.088,0 202.459,15.4173 183.155,39.476C 172.643,34.688 160.972,32 148.667,32C 113.536,32 83.504,53.7493 71.2467,84.5093C 68.652,84.1853 66.016,84 63.3333,84C 28.356,84 -1.5625e-005,112.355 -1.5625e-005,147.333C -1.5625e-005,182.311 28.356,210.667 63.3333,210.667L 429.333,213.333C 449.952,213.333 466.667,196.619 466.667,176C 466.667,163.555 460.572,152.54 451.211,145.756 Z "/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Use in page

```
<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource PIPause}"
                                    Height="20"
                                    Width="20" />
```

Answer (score 1):

A pause button in XAML:

```
<Grid Width="60">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Rectangle  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="70" Width="20"   Stroke="Black" />
    <Rectangle Grid.Column="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="70" Width="20"  Stroke="Black" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a `PathGeometry` with two separate `PathFigures`, e.g.:

```
private Path CreatePauseButton()
{
    Path p = new Path();

    p.StrokeThickness = 0.0;
    p.Fill = Brushes.Gray;

    p.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    p.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;

    double f = 1.0 / 7.0;
    Point start = new Point(PlayButtonSize * f, 0.0);

    //the left rectangle:
    LineSegment[] segments = new[]
    {
                new LineSegment(new Point(PlayButtonSize * f, PlayButtonSize), true),
                new LineSegment(new Point((PlayButtonSize * f) * 3.0, PlayButtonSize), true),
                new LineSegment(new Point((PlayButtonSize * f) * 3.0, 0.0), true),
                new LineSegment(new Point(PlayButtonSize * f, 0.0), true),
                new LineSegment(new Point((PlayButtonSize * f) * 4, PlayButtonSize), false)
            };

    //the right rectangle:

    LineSegment[] segments2 = new[]
    {
                ...
            };

    PathFigure figure = new PathFigure(start, segments, true);
    PathFigure figure2 = new PathFigure(start, segments2, true);
    PathGeometry geometry = new PathGeometry(new[] { figure, figure2 });

    p.Margin = new Thickness(16.0, 0, 0, 8.0);
    p.Data = geometry;

    p.MouseEnter += (s, e) => { p.Fill = Brushes.LightGray; };
    p.MouseLeave += (s, e) => { p.Fill = Brushes.Gray; };

    return p;
}
```

**How to: Create Multiple Subpaths Within a PathGeometry:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-create-multiple-subpaths-within-a-pathgeometry